# Copy directory recursively only if on target the file exists and only if newer than target

Tags: synchronization

How can we copy file and/or directory only if on target the file exists and only if it is newer than on target, and for the directory case it must **recursively** copy with such capability
as

```
 $ ls -a ~/.config
 gtk-2.0/             
 gtk-3.0/
 SpeedCrunch/

 $ ls -a /other/path/home/.config/
 gtk-2.0/             
 gtk-3.0/
 SpeedCrunch/


$ rsync -u --existing ~/.config /other/path/home/
skipping directory .
```

can't work.

What Linux utility and how to do/solve it ? Thank you before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick:**

You forgot to include the recursive switch "-r" :

```
rsync -u --existing -r ~/.config /other/path/home/
```

**Extra Stuff:**

Also, you may consider using `-a` switch which is equal to `-rlptgoD` to include recursive in addition to preserve some important attributes as follows:

- -r: recurse into directories
- -l: copy symlinks as symlinks
- -p: preserve permissions
- -t: preserve modification times
- -g: preserve group
- -o: preserve owner (super-user only)
- -D: preserve special files same as --devices --specials

Use follows for testing:

```
mkdir src
touch src/file{1..3}
touch src/thefile
# Destination:
mkdir dst
touch dst/file{1..3}
touch -d 20201023 dst/thefile
# List all
free -D src dst
```

Try now:

```
rsync -rt -uPv --existing src dst/
```

I used:

- -r: recurse into directories
- -t: preserve modification times
- -u: skip files that are newer on the receiver
- -P: show progress during transfer
- -v: increase verbosity
- --existing: skip creating new files on receiver

Comment: THANKS BILLIONS